# Having issue with codeigniter 4 filters

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-4

I have an application that has both traditional web app and the RestAPI with JWT I have a filter called JwtFilter with the alias of jwt but its working on all api/* routes I want to not apply on the api/auth/login and api/auth/register but I couldn't find how. My auth filter which is for WebApp is working just fine having an issue with the jwt.

**Filter.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

use App\Filters\AuthFilter;
use App\Filters\JwtFilter;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;

class Filters extends BaseConfig {
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'     => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'  => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot' => Honeypot::class,
        'auth'     => AuthFilter::class,
        'jwt'      => JwtFilter::class,
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
            'auth' => ['except' => 'auth/*'],
        ],
        'after'  => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that works on a
     * particular HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).
     *
     * Example:
     * 'post' => ['csrf', 'throttle']
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $methods = [];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that should run on any
     * before or after URI patterns.
     *
     * Example:
     * 'isLoggedIn' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $filters = [
        'jwt' => [
            'before' => ['api/*', 'api'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `$filters` doesn't allow you to add an array of 'except' URIs like `$globals` does. You'll have to get 'creative':

- You could [inspect the URI in the filter itself](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#the-request-url) and sidestep the URIs you don't want.
- You could be more specific in your definition of `$filters`
- You could reorganize your URI structure; does `auth/` need to be behind `api/`?